# Injecting JQuery Cross-Domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, jsonp, xss

Is it safe to inject JQuery's script using JsonP?

The installation of my web application is - adding a script to a customer's website (like google analytics). I was thinking of using JQuery on the customer's website, as part of my own injected script.

I was wondering, if there is some kind of risk?
The application needs to support any kind of website.

Thank you
Yaron

Comment: Just a note, but JSON-P is a specific technology that relates to JSON not normal JavaScript. You are talking about simply including an external javacript file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its hard to tell what you are doing with your library, but it seems you are building some type of widget for use on multiple sites.

*From here down has been updated after an enlightening comment from @K Prime caused me research exactly how you could include two copies of jQuery if needed:*

It is *generally* bad to use jQuery if you are building a widget that will live on a site *outside* your control, and will be added to the site with a "copy this embed code and paste onto your site" type of functionality. *(Of course jQuery widgets and plugins abound, but these are normally chosen and installed/implemented by developers not a generic "copy-n-paste" widget type implementation)*

Probably the biggest reason (after realizing you *can* run two copies of jQuery on the same page) is the file size increase. Whether it is warranted will depend on your particular needs and function. Simple small widget = straight JS. Complex website front-end extension, then it probably is worth the file-size increase.

To include it properly (so you don't run into conflicts on their site) follow a workflow that looks something like this:

1. Dynamically add jQuery to their page using the Google APIs as mentioned on the other answers here.
2. Run `var mywidget_jQuery = $.noConflict( true );` which will restore the original meaning of `$` *and* restore the original meaning of `window.jQuery`.
3. Dynamically add your script file, but be sure to wrap the entire thing in a self executing anonymous function like this:

**JS**

```
(function($){
    ... Your code here ...
})(mywidget_jQuery);
```

Now, you can safely use `$` inside your special function and all the jQuery features you want without issue.

**Extra credit** You could wrap steps 1 and 2 in an if statement that tests if `window.jQuery` is defined and if it, test if `jQuery.fn.version` is high enough to run your code. If either test fails, then run steps 1 and 2. If it passes, however, then just run `var mywidget_jQuery = window.jQuery` so the script you include in step 3 will still run.

Comment: He could check `jQuery.fn.version`, use `jQuery.noConflict (true)`, and define his functions inside a closure - that should ensure his widget is in its own bubble

Comment: @K Prime, you are totally correct. Woah that was a big update, but my answer is actually accurate now. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

You can add jQuery to a website by simply adding a `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.js" />` element.

However, make sure to call [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict) in case they use a different `$` keyword.

Comment: +1, I just knew that they have latest copy on /1.3/jquery.js and /1/jquery.js

Answer (score 0):

If you're just after a reference to the library, why wouldn't you just link to the API hosted on [Google Code](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js)?